# how to let a image clickable and link to a page i want in html5

Tags: asp.net, html

How to let a image clickable and link to a page I want in html 5

How to let a image clickable and link to a page I want in html 5

How to let a image clickable and link to a page I want in html 5

Where should I write the code, in source or code. And what is the code?

Using a herf = "#"    ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a image clickable on a page, you don't need HTML5 as it it's supported in all browsers day and night. I mean... it's standard.

```
<a href="link_page.html"><img src="image_source.jpg" alt="Alternate title" /></a>
```

Is this what you're getting at?

edit: It is clear to me that you're a beginner. That's okay -- we all once were one, too. Please visit this link to begin your adventure: http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/web

PS - Have fun.

Comment: Yeah, I just figure out myself, thanks anyway!

Comment: wo zhi dao, shi jian mei dao bu neng dian zan